# Issue with AttachTo method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For updating record in Entity framework I am trying that. I am just assigning  primary key CompanyID and The name of Company CompanyName to `company` because I need to change company name only. Record is not updating.

```
using (var myentity= new MyEntities())
{
    myentity.AttachTo("Companies", company);
    myentity.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to first attach it and only after that set the company name.

Something like this:

```
var company = new Company;
company.CompanyID = yourID;

using (var myentity= new MyEntities())
{
    myentity.AttachTo("Companies", company);
    company.CompanyName = newName;
    myentity.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: getting this exception :  Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: Make sure the value in `yourID` is the ID of an existing entry in the database.

Comment: yes! work fine, Can u tell me what is reason to attach first?

Comment: Only after you attached the entity to the context it is monitored by EF. All changes to a "monitored" entity are saved and translated into SQL once you call `SaveChanges`. When you set the company name before you attach the entity to the context, the entity is not yet monitored and so the context doesn't know about the change you made and hence doesn't generate an update statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough. If you assigned `CompanyName` before attaching the company you must tell EF that it has changed. Otherwise you must assign it after the company was attached so the EF can track the change for you as (@Daniel described);

```
using (var myentity= new MyEntities())
{
    myentity.AttachTo("Companies", company);
    ObjectStateEntry entry = myentity.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(company);
    entry.SetModifiedProperty("CompanyName"); 
    myentity.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: getting exception : The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a reference to an object of type 'DAL.MyEntities'.

Comment: If possible, my solution should be used as it supports refactoring.

Comment: @Daniel: Sure this is not very nice implementation in EF but it can be wrapped to support strongly typed lambdas as well. DbContext API supports strongly typed lambdas out of the box.